# IE SSO settings for org website over intranet & internet

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, single-sign-on, kerberos, saml

We have unsolicited SAML SSO URL implemented for a service used by corp users. 
When users access the URL from intrAnet, they are authenticated using Kerberos token. When users access the URL from intErnet, they are requested to enter username/password (since kerberos fails) to complete authentication. 
This works perfectly from Firefox, Chrome. 
However for IE,

- if we add the URL to intranet zone, kerberos authentication works on intranet but the website is not reachable when accessed from internet.
- if we do not add the user to intranet zone then, IE prompts for username/password on both intranet & internet so (pure) kerberos over intranet does not work. (Out IT team won't allow to change internet zone logon setting from "Automatic logon only in Intranet only" to "Automatic logon with current user name and password")
- I am not sure what are risks of adding the URL to trusted URL and changing logon setting to "Automatic logon with current user name and password".

What is the correct IE setting so that when users access the URL from intranet they are authenticated using kerberos and when they access from internet they are prompted user name/password ?

Thanks in advance.